# Laravel Controller function not returning row with primary key

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I have a problem in my resource controller. When I am try to get the row to delete record with `destroy` function like I described below it does not work.

```
public function destroy(SubCategory $subCategory)
{

$subCategory->delete();

}
```

but if I try some thing like below, it works

```
public function destroy($subCategory)
{

SubCategory::find($subCategory)->delete();

}
```

I just want to do that with the first one, I do not know why it's not working?

Comment: It depends on what your `$subCategory` object contains. Try `dd($subCategory)` and paste the output here.

Comment: SubCategory {#189
  #guarded: []
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #events: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
}

Answer (score 1):

Try to define Your model in `RouteServiceProvider` or directly on `routes.php` file before resource directive:

```
public function boot(Router $router)
{
    parent::boot($router);

    Route::model('subCategory', App\SubCategory::class);
}
```

[image: route service provider example]

read about: [explicit binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-model-binding)

Answer (score 0):

I found an error in my web.php file.It's my mistake I define my resource route like that

```
  Route::resource('subcategory', 'SubCategoryController');
```

but it should be like below

```
Route::resource('subCategory', 'SubCategoryController');
```